# How can I find where a point will touch a line given a vector?

Tags: math, vector, geometry, plane

[image]

Here, line segment ab is cast upward on arbitrary vector n where I do somethings to find the black point on the line segment cd. My question is, how do I find the point on ab that intersects with the inverted n vector coming down from the new point?

Comment: what you have already seen and tried. to solve this problem on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it will have the same x-coordinate as the black point (call this x). The slope of ab is m = (b<sub>y</sub> - a<sub>y</sub>) / (b<sub>x</sub> - a<sub>x</sub>), so the y coordinate is mx + a<sub>y</sub>.

Comment: It's not necessarily vertical though. What I meant by arbitrary is that it can have any direction.

Answer (score 0):

If the projection is parallel, by the Thales theorem the ratios are preserved.

```
|ae| / |ab| = |cf| / |cd| = r
```

which is known.

The searched point is, vectorially

```
e = a + r.ab = a + |cf|/|cd|.ab
```